# How to send mail with google app engine

Tags: php, google-app-engine

I can send mail with PHPMailer using Google's servers. It turned out the limit of sent emails is 99/day. So I digged deeper and found that I can use Google App Engine to send emails for $0.0001 with a 1.7 millions/day limit.

I have a VPS running CentOS that I access via Putty (I have basic linux knowledge) and CPanel. I installed Python and the [App Engine PHP SDK](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/php/gettingstarted/installinglinux#SDK). The PHP version is 5.4.22.

I would like to send mail with the [given example](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/php/mail/#PHP_Sending_mail) but I am stuck at the first line. While the php file is in the public_html folder, the appengine is installed outside:

```
root@server1 [~]# locate Message.php
/root/google_appengine/php/sdk/google/appengine/api/mail/Message.php
```

The code:

```
<?php
require_once 'google/appengine/api/mail/Message.php';
use google\appengine\api\mail\Message;

$message_body = 'Hello. This is the body of the message.';

$mail_options = [
  'sender' => 'support@mycompany.com',
  'to' => 'myname@gmail.com',
  'subject' => 'Your account has been activated.',
  'textBody' => $message_body
];

try {
  $message = new Message($mail_options);
  $message->send();
} catch (InvalidArgumentException $e) {
    echo 'error: ';
}
?>
```

So I get the obvious error:

```
Warning: require_once(google/appengine/api/mail/Message.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/mycompany/public_html/test_googleappsmail.php on line 2
```

Furthermore, the docs are not clear if I should do anything in the Google Developer Console. I created a project but I have no idea what to do with it. All I want is to send e-mails.

Could anyone point me into the right direction and tell me how to use this code?

Comment: have you tried with an absolute path?

Comment: You do realize that the SDK is not the same thing as running on production, and is purely to test and develop locally? In any case, to run the SDK you need to use dev_appserver.py - follow these insructions: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/php/gettingstarted/helloworld

Comment: No, I didn't realize that. I saw this link, it's very scanty. Where do I put the helloworld folder? Btw, if the SDK is for development purposes only, then how am I supposed to send email with app engine?

Comment: Start here -> https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/php/gettingstarted/introduction

Comment: If anyone knows, please share your knowledge. At the end, I turned to SendGrid and implemented their API within 30 minutes and I am happily sending emails since.

Comment: Couldn't agree more with @erdomester, its way too difficult to understand the basics of setting up and using google services, AWS' docs are not that great either but still better than the one google has

Answer (score 4):

I created a simple demo of Google App Engine - PHP - Mail API.

Github Repository : https://github.com/sasidhar/gae-php-mail

It is working fine with the default settings.

Hope this helps.

**PHP Code Snippet**

```
use \google\appengine\api\mail\Message;

try {

    $message = new Message();
    $message->setSender("sasidhar@sasidhar.com");
    $message->addTo($email);
    $message->setSubject($subject);
    $message->setTextBody($mailBody);
    $message->send();

    header("Location: /mail_sent");

} catch (InvalidArgumentException $e) {

    $error = "Unable to send mail. $e";
}
```

Comment: is we nee to instal composer?

Comment: how can we install composer?

Comment: Sadly, this has been discontinued: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php7/php-differences#migrating_from_the_app_engine_php_sdk:~:text=App%20Engine%20Mail%20API%20support%20is%20not%20provided